# Java - Failed to execute AQL query

Tags: java, arangodb

How to fix AQL syntax error?
I'm trying to create an edge using a query, but the following error appears:

> Failed to execute query. Response: 400, Error: 1501 - AQL: syntax error, unexpected end of query string near '@edges' at position 1:57 (while parsing)

The code used to execute the query:

```
try {

 String query = "INSERT { _from:TurmaA._teste2, _to:TurmaA._testepedro } IN @edges";
 Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("edges", nome2).get();
 ArangoCursor<BaseDocument> cursor = arangoDB.db(dbName).query(query, bindVars, 
null, BaseDocument.class);

cursor.forEachRemaining(aDocument -> {
  System.out.println("Key: " + aDocument.getKey());
 });
} catch (ArangoDBException e) {
 System.err.println("Failed to execute query. " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that [collection bind variables have to be prefixed by two `@@`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Fundamentals/BindParameters.html).

So your code example can probably be easily fixed like this:

```java
try {

 String query = "INSERT { _from:TurmaA._teste2, _to:TurmaA._testepedro } IN @@edges";
 Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("@edges", nome2).get();
 ArangoCursor<BaseDocument> cursor = arangoDB.db(dbName).query(query, bindVars, 
null, BaseDocument.class);

cursor.forEachRemaining(aDocument -> {
  System.out.println("Key: " + aDocument.getKey());
 });
} catch (ArangoDBException e) {
 System.err.println("Failed to execute query. " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: thanks! that did work, but now i have another problem... it says  
   `collection or view not found: testepedro`     but i checked and it is in the right collection

Comment: Please try it out on the webinterface, It offers more easy means of debugging. Please note that its case sensitive.

Comment: very helpfull I was trying to find this